# Numbering of Dropdown Options XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

xslt1.0 preferably

I have the following xslt code that is recreated for the amount of productguarantee selected. So say I pick 5 I get the below dropdown 5 times. At the moment when anything over 1 is selected it will number each of them sequentially.

What I want is for it to only number items that are the same e.g. if B is selected 3 times it will be B 1, B 2, B 3.

And the tricky part is there is an 'other' box where user can type freetext so if this matches another other box then they will be numbered but I'm not too worried about this part for the moment.

At the moment say you select 5 products you will get:

OptionOne 1, OptionOne 2, OptionTwo 3, OptionFour 4, OptionFive 5

What I would like is you get only numbering for multiples e.g.

OptionOne 1, Option One 2, OptionTwo, OptionFour, OptionFive

Any help greatly appreciated

Code:

```
<xsl:if test="productguarantee!=0">
<xsl:for-each select="productguarantees/productguaranteedata">
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected'">OptionOne</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='B']='selected'">OptionTwo</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='C']='selected'">OptionThree</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='D']='selected'">OptionFour</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='E']='selected'">OptionFive</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='F']='selected'">OptionSix</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='G']='selected'">OptionSeven</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='H']='selected'"><xsl:value-of select="otherprodtypebox"/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="(../../productguarantee)!='1'">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

XML:

```
<productguarantee>0</productguarantee>
    <productguarantees>
        <productguaranteedata id="0">
            <producttypes>
                <option id="A">selected</option>
                <option id="B"/>
                <option id="C"/>
                <option id="D"/>
                <option id="E"/>
                <option id="F"/>
                <option id="G"/>
                <option id="H"/>
            </producttypes>
            <otherprodtypebox/>
        </productguaranteedata>
</productguarantees>
```

Comment: first, please provide an xml sample, and also an associated expected output. (best if the buggy output is here also)

Comment: @BiAiB added now. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I'm possibly thinking something like this may work <xsl:for-each select="productguarantees/productguaranteedata/producttypes/option[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('productOption', @id)[1]) or @id = 'otherprodtype']"><xsl:sort select="count(preceding-sibling::option)" data-type="number" />

Comment: How is it possible that "B is selected 3 times", when there is only *one* `<option id="B"/>` ??? Please, edit the question and explain.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev its a wizard screen so you can choose from 1 to 99 productguarantee and you will get this dropdown question for each screen. So you pick 10 you get this question ten times. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not the most elegant solution, but time is limited and I found that changing your individual xsl:if statements to something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected'">
    <xsl:text>OptionOne</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="
        preceding-sibling::productguaranteedata[producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected']
        or 
        following-sibling::productguaranteedata[producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected']                    
    ">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

(example for Product A, you would have to change the other xsl:if statements accordingly)

and skipping the xsl:if at the end of the loop might help.

**EDIT:**

```
<xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected'">
    <xsl:text>OptionOne</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="
        preceding-sibling::productguaranteedata[producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected']
        or 
        following-sibling::productguaranteedata[producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected']                    
    ">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::productguaranteedata[producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected'])+1"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: this appears to nearly work the way I want but I want the counter to start at 1 for new products e.g. with this code I get A 1, A 2, B 3, B 4, C but ideally I'd like A 1, A 2, B 1, B 2, C . I hope that makes sense. Thanks for all the help

Comment: brilliant. top quality answer and I learnt from it too. Thank you very much